# ICollectionView фильтр

Tags: c#, wpf, uicollectionview

Имеется некая коллекция объектов, которая отображается пользователю. Данные объекты(которые хранятся в коллекции) "живые" - то есть некоторые их свойства могут меняться со временем. При добавлении нового объекта в коллекцию происходит фильтрация(Filter) и только объекты, у которых поле _SyncCreated имеет состояние true, отображаются. Однако после добавления данные объекты могут сменить состояние на false  и их, соответственно, показывать больше не нужно. Я делаю refresh данной вьюшки, однако результата не вижу. Примечательно то, что если сменить фокус элемента, к которому привязана коллекция на другой, а после вернуться - я буду видеть только объекты с нужным состоянием, но в дальнейшем, если не менять фокус, опять начинается помойка. Подскажите пожалуйста, как фильтровать всю коллекцию, а не только новые приходящие элементы. Или же как правильно рефрешить коллекцию без "передерргиваний".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, `ICollectionView` обновляется лишь когда изменяется сама коллекция, или явно вызвана функция Refresh.

Вы должны воспользоваться более современным [`ICollectionViewLiveShaping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionviewliveshaping.aspx). Согласно документации, `ListCollectionView`, `BindingListCollectionView`, `ItemCollection` и `CollectionViewSource` реализуют этот интерфейс.

Вы должны установить свойство [`LiveFilteringProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionviewliveshaping.livefilteringproperties.aspx) и `IsLiveFilteringRequested = true`. Не забудьте, что ваш тип объекта в коллекции должен имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChange`, и что с полями фокус не пройдёт, нужно именно свойство.

Пример:

```
<CollectionViewSource
    Source="{Binding Items}" Filter="OnFilter" IsLiveFilteringRequested="True">
    <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        <!-- вам придётся завести такое *поле* -->
        <sys:String>SyncCreated</system:String>
    </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: В очередной раз премного Вам благодарен. Завтра обязательно испытаю!

Comment: @Sleeeper: Не за что!

Answer (score 2):

Как и указал VladD, необходимо пользоваться ICollectionViewLiveShaping.Однако если работа ведется в .net FrameWork < 4.5 ver. , увидеть данную фичу не получится. Решение, которое мне удалось найти, прямиком по ссылке:
[Реализация CollectionViewLiveShaping с поддержкой старых версий фреймворков](http://www.shujaat.net/2014/02/wpf-collectionviewsource-and-live.html)

Comment: Ох. А нет возможности накатить .NET 4.5? (А лучше и 4.6.) Вроде ж там всё стало намного лучше.

Comment: к сожалению, такой возможности нет(