# Bindable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Как то давно видел такую штуку и никак не вспомню где и как называлось. В общем есть коллекция объектов которая биндится к контролу (например TabControl). Но у объектов есть флаг булевый и объекты у которых он false не должны отображаться. Единственное решение которое напрашивается - иметь две параллельные коллекции. Но это значило бы что надо в них параллельно добавлять и удалять элементы. Это довольно неудобно (а вдруг где забудешь). Так вот мне смутно помниться что я видел где то коллекции которые можно забиндить на другие коллекции. Есть ли такое? Чтобы эта коллекция отфильтровывала по флагу нужные элементы и биндинг на нее. Но в то же время если первая коллекция изменится чтобы вторая тоже автоматом менялась.

P.S. Ну или если есть возможность это простой xaml-разметкой без ухищрений сделать то так даже лучше было бы.

Comment: Никто не знает? :(

Comment: Свойство, которое решает, отображать ли элемент - есть в самом элементе или его надо добавлять поверх?

Comment: Есть. (15 раз есть)

Comment: Забиндить его на Visibility (через стандартный конвертер) - по моему получится то что надо.

Answer (score 1):

`List<foo> filtred = collection.Where(i => i.BoolParam == true).ToList();`

Нэ?

Comment: Вообще не в ту степь. Там же биндинг должен быть. Кто его вручную обновлять то будет. Впрочем уже немного не актуально, а имелось ввиду что-то вроде [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448958/icollectionview-фильтр?rq=1)

Comment: Ну можно мессенджером из MVVM-Light (или чем-то подобным). но соглашусь - по ссылке более разумное решение, я про него не знал. Спасибо)